# Need to replace DLookup with something more efficient

Tags: sql, performance, ms-access-2016

I think I've just gone brain numb thinking about this. I have an Access query that does exactly what I want it to do. But I did it with an IIF which includes a DLookup. It takes several minutes to run. If I replace the DLookup with just a quote, it runs in seconds. So I know it's the DLookup that's causing all the delay. I've redesigned this query 20x trying different join methods, but I've got to be missing something.

I have several tables
qryUniqueDevices has an Official Name which won't make sense to 99% of people.
tblDeviceCategoryDB has, for most products, a good device type and category.
qryDevType has generic types for all devices based on the Official Name.
If the device doesn't have a specific type listed in tblDeviceCategoryDB, I want to use the generic type that's listed in qryDevType.

```
SELECT qryUniqueDevices.[Official Name], qryUniqueDevices.Manufacturer, qryUniqueDevices.Model, 
IIf(IsNull([tblDeviceCategoryDB].[DevType]),
DLookUp("DevType","qryDevType","[Official Name] = '" & [qryUniqueDevices].[Official Name] & "'"),[tblDeviceCategoryDB].[DevType]) AS DevType, tblDeviceCategoryDB.DevCat, tblDeviceCategoryDB.ID
FROM qryUniqueDevices
LEFT JOIN tblDeviceCategoryDB ON (qryUniqueDevices.Model = tblDeviceCategoryDB.Model) AND (qryUniqueDevices.Manufacturer = tblDeviceCategoryDB.Manufacturer) AND (qryUniqueDevices.[Official Name] = tblDeviceCategoryDB.[Official Name]);
```

If the device doesn't have a specific type listed in tblDeviceCategoryDB, I want to use the generic type that's listed in qryDevType. Right now it works, but takes 3-5 minutes to run because of that stupid DLookup.

Comment: I suspect you already know this, but: `Although you can use the DLookup function to display a value from a field in a foreign table, it may be more efficient to create a query that contains the fields that you need from both tables and then to base your form or report on that query.`:  [MS Documentation: DLookup Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/dlookup-function-8896cb03-e31f-45d1-86db-bed10dca5937)

Comment: You'll have to [provide](http://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) sample data and expected result for us to be able to help you.
[How to ask a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271). Sample data and expected result is much more useful than a textual description. Sample data != real data.